# Adding css in a button link

Tags: css, button

how to add a link style in a button.
So, i have a link style:

```
a:link {color:#FFFFFF;}
a:visited {color:#FFFFFF;}
a:hover {color:#FFFFFF;}
a:active {color:#FFFFFF;}
```

how to integrate this style with this button css.

```
button {
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000000;
font: bold 11px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 17px;
height: 18px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px 6px 4px 6px;
background: #F3F3F3;
border: solid 1px #D9D9D9;
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
 -webkit-transition: border-color .20s;
 -moz-transition: border-color .20s;
 -o-transition: border-color .20s;
 transition: border-color .20s;
height: 29px !important;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly ... "integrate"?

Comment: well, if i use `a:link {color:#FFFFFF;}
a:visited {color:#FFFFFF;}
a:hover {color:#FFFFFF;}
a:active {color:#FFFFFF;}` in .css file then all links going to be white, but i want to change the color of links only in buttons..

Comment: Change `a:link` to `button a:link {` etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the same style applied to multiple elements (and type of elements) then you should be using classes.

```
.link:link {color:#FFFFFF;}
.link:visited {color:#FFFFFF;}
.link:hover {color:#FFFFFF;}
.link:active {color:#FFFFFF;}

.button { all of your button styles }
```

Then use them together when you need them together:

```
<input type="button" class="link button" value="I'm a button" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `button a:link, button a:hover, button a:visited, button a:active`.

But what's the point of having a link inside a button?

Answer (score 0):

I not understand  very well the question but maybe this can serve you:

```
INPUT:hover {background: yellow;}
INPUT:focus {background: #FF99FF;}
INPUT:focus:hover {background: #99FF99;}
```

or

```
INPUT:focus:hover {
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000000;
font: bold 11px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 17px;
height: 18px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px 6px 4px 6px;
background: #F3F3F3;
border: solid 1px #D9D9D9;
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
 -webkit-transition: border-color .20s;
 -moz-transition: border-color .20s;
 -o-transition: border-color .20s;
 transition: border-color .20s;
height: 29px !important;
cursor: pointer;

}
```